# Error while scrapinig data from Binance.US

Tags: python, web-scraping, data-science, linear-regression, cryptocurrency

I am a data science noob. I am attempting to scrape some data from the Binance API so I can play around with multiple linear regression. However, I'm encountering an issue with pulling the data from Binance. Here's my code:

```
def get_binance_bars(symbol, interval, startTime, endTime):
 

    url = "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines"
 
    startTime = str(int(startTime.timestamp() * 1000))
    endTime = str(int(endTime.timestamp() * 1000))
    limit = '1000'
 
    req_params = {"symbol" : symbol, 'interval' : interval, 'startTime' : startTime, 'endTime' : endTime, 'limit' : limit}
 
    df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(requests.get(url, params = req_params).text))
 
    if (len(df.index) == 0):
        return None
  
    df = df.iloc[:, 0:6]
    df.columns = ['datetime', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']
 
    df.open      = df.open.astype("float")
    df.high      = df.high.astype("float")
    df.low       = df.low.astype("float")
    df.close     = df.close.astype("float")
    df.volume    = df.volume.astype("float")

    df['adj_close'] = df['close']
 
    df.index = [dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(x / 1000.0) for x in df.datetime]
 
    return df
```

This all works fantastically. Then, I try to use this to pull the data from specific time frames.

```
months = [dt.datetime(2021, i, 1) for i in range(1, 13)]
df_list = [get_binance_bars('MATIC-USD', '1h', months[i], months[i+1] - dt.timedelta(0, 1)) for i in range(0, len(months) - 1)]
df = pd.concat(df_list)
```

The error message I'm getting is "ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index"

I thought I was passing through an index? Keep in mind, I'm still trying to figure this out. I'm sure it's something simple. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: could you please share sample arguments to call `get_binance_bars()`? I want to reproduce the problem.

Comment: get_binance_bars('MATIC-USD', '1h', dt.datetime(2021, 1, 1), dt.datetime(2021, 5, 5))